# In PyQt, do I need to disconnect from signals when discarding an item?

Tags: pyqt, signals

I'm using PyQt to build an interface where multiple components listen for changes in a data model using new-style signals. Sometimes, QGraphicsItems are created and connected to signals in the model. When a part of the model is deleted, the graphics scene removes the item again. My question is: Do I need to disconnect the signal first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PyQt/Python will do that automatically for you.

Comment: For such a simple question you should probably provide a reference to the statement in pyqt docs that says this